# How to integrate python3-flake8 with Atom in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, atom-editor

I installed python3-flake8 on Ubuntu 16.04 with the command *sudo apt-get install python3-flake8*
Then proceeded to install the flake8 linter package on Atom.
However on restart it shows the following error
*Error: spawn flake8 ENOENT*.

I do not know if atom is able to detect flake8 on my system or if it is some other kind of problem.

Error message:

```
Error: spawn flake8 ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Is that your *entire* error message? Don't you get some sort of traceback below that?

Comment: Hi sorry for not posting the complete error. Error: spawn flake8 ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: Could you try running `flake8` in your terminal? Does that work or is the command not found?

Comment: @Aurora0001 thanks. I ran flake8 and it told me to install flake8. So ran apt install flake8 this time. I do not know why apt install python3-flake8 won't work or if it is different.

Comment: `python3-flake8` apparently doesn't include the binary, just the bindings to Python 3. Is your problem now solved then, and if so, would you like me to post this as an answer?

Comment: @Aurora0001 yes. It has been resolved. And is working fine. Please post the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From Ubuntu 16.04, the `flake8` binary can be found in the `flake8` package rather than `python3-flake8` ([Xenial/16.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/flake8) and [Yakkety/16.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/flake8)). Installing this will allow you to use the `flake8` command in the terminal, and will also allow Atom to access it and lint your code.

You can install `flake8` correctly with:

```
sudo apt-get install flake8
```

Comment: I was struggling for a day with this issue. I was installing flake8 with pip and atom was still giving me errors, even though I added it to PATH and it was returning "which flake8" command in the terminal. Working perfectly with apt-get installation.