# Getting error when running flake 8 on Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

I installed the linter flake 8 package on Atom, and I did the pip installation, but for some reason linter isn't functioning it always displays the following error:

> Linter] Error running Flake8 See Console for more info. (Open View ->
>   Developer -> Toggle Developer Tools)

Answer (score 1):

Double-check you pip installed flake8 properly - it should be installed system-wide (not in a virtualenv) and should be available on your PATH, so if you say `which flake8` you should get something like `/usr/local/bin/flake8`.

Also if you open devtools like the error suggests, it might give you some clues as to what else might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pip, try to install flake8 using terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install flake8
```

More information 
[How to integrate python3-flake8 with Atom in Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548524/how-to-integrate-python3-flake8-with-atom-in-ubuntu-16-04)